# Is there any way to write '\r' into a file on linux with python?

Tags: python, linux, file

To follow a protocol, '\r\n' can't be replaced by '\n'

But when I wrote the string below into a file with python, '\r\n' were all replaced by '\n'

```
"*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n"
```

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), Python on Linux makes no distinction between text and binary files, so no matter I append a 'b' to the mode or not, there is no difference, all '\r' were gone

How to solve this? Any help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: How do you confirm that the `\r` is gone?

Comment: open the file with vim/gvim, '\r' will be dispalyed as '^M' @falsetru

Comment: `vim` automatically detect the fileformat (ff in short, line-ennding). Try `:set ff`. It will show you `fileformat=dos` if the file consistently have `\r\n`. Otherwise, it will show you `fileformat=unix` and `^M` as you commented.

Comment: Instead of opening the file with `vim`. Try `xxd filename` to see the raw bytes as hexadecimal format. It will not hide CR (`0d` in hex).

Comment: thanks, it's helpful! \r were not gone! Can you add a answer? then I can make it as the best answer@falsetru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as you said.

One possible reason you don't see the `\r` is that the editor you're using detect the fileformat (line ending) and hide the CR.

### VIM

For example, vim automatically detect the fileformat (ff). Try `:set ff`. It will show you `fileformat=dos` if the file consistently have `\r\n`. Otherwise, it will show you fileformat=unix and ^M as you commented.

Try `xxd filename` to see the raw bytes as hexadecimal format. It will not hide CR (`0d` in hex)